# jQuery Calender - unable to see gif

Tags: jquery

Issue: The calender.gif does not show so I can not get the calender function.

Tried: I have the jQuery calender working on another project and am a bit stumped as to why it is not working now.

I have ensured that the image is actually in the jquery folder to fix any folder issues, checked the image exists and also that the content placeholder is correct with source view for the `ctl00_body_lblDateEnd` part.

I have also tried putting and taking away both '#' and 'ct100_body_'

CSS and jQuery links both look correct and not errors from the console and I have rechecked them by dragging in as well.

Anything I am missing...?  a `#` or `'` somewhere?!

I have one hidden and one unhidden for testing on the vb.net side.

Code:

jquery

```
// Variables passed out here from the functions as we can not check inputs


var lblDateStart = '<%= lblDateStart.ClientId %>';
function setLabelStart(yourDate1) {
    $("ctl00_Body_lblDateStart").val(yourDate1);
}

var lblDateEnd = '<%= lblDateEnd.ClientId %>';
function setLabelEnd(yourDate2) {
    $("#ctl00_body_lblDateEnd").val(yourDate2);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({
        //display month drop down
        changeMonth: true,
        //display year drop down
        changeYear: true,
        //date format
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        //calender image
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        //multiple months
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        //show 'done' button
        //showButtonPanel: true,
        // Default Date
        defaultDate: "-4w",
        //pass value to variable
        onSelect: setLabelStart
    });
});

//More than one date? You need to scripts

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepickerTo").datepicker({
        //display month drop down
        changeMonth: true,
        //display year drop down
        changeYear: true,
        //date format
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        //calender image
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        //multiple months
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        //show 'done' button
        //showButtonPanel: true,
        // Default Date
        defaultDate: "+0w",
        //pass value to variable
        onSelect: setLabelEnd
    });
});
```

Main page .aspx
<

```
%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/gateway/MasterPageTEST.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="holiday.aspx.vb" Inherits="Holiday" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" Runat="Server">



    <!-- // Disable enter key due to multiple submit buttons!! \\ --> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    function stopRKey(evt) {
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) { return false; }
    }

    document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>

<!-- Calender Functions -->   
<link href="../../css/Calender.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="../../jQuery/CalenderFunctionality.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../jQuery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--//Resize the calender here -->
<style type="text/css">
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;  background: #blue}
</style>
<!-- // calender functions -->
<!-- \\ Disable enter key due to multiple submit buttons!! // --> 


 <!-- ######################### //BODY CODE UNIQUE TO PAGE \\ ######################### -->

<!-- ######################### //HEADER CODE UNIQUE TO PAGE \\ ######################### -->
<!-- ######################### \\HEADER CODE UNIQUE TO PAGE // ######################### -->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftBarImage" Runat="Server">
    <!-- ######################### //Left hand banner image \\ ######################### -->

      <img src="/gateway/photos/gateway_3.jpg" alt="Page Preview" />


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftBarNotes" Runat="Server">
        <div id="Points_box"> 
        <h3>Quick Notes</h3>

            <div id="Side1" class="SmallBar"> 
            </div> <!-- Side1 -->

            <span id="Gold1" class="Gold"> 
            </span><!-- Gold -->

            <div id="Pad20B" class="Pad20">
            </div> <!-- Pad20B -->
        </div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" Runat="Server">

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GWmyPemcoSQL %>"      
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblHolidayRequests] WHERE ([EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID) order by ID desc;"   >            

          <SelectParameters>

              <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="xyz999" Name="EmployeeID" SessionField="EmployeeID" 
                  Type="string" />
          </SelectParameters>
                       </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:Panel ID="PanelMain" runat="server" Visible="true">



 <div id="WrapperBlock" class="WrapperBlock"> 
            <div id="Block1" class="Block1">
            <h3>
              Book a Holiday </h3>
            </div>   <!-- Block1 -->   
        <div id="Block2" class="Block2">       
               <%-- <asp:Button ID="btnPDTR" runat="server" CssClass="btnFloatRight" Text="View Your PDTR" />--%>
         </div><!-- Block2 -->  
     </div><!-- WrapperBlock -->  

<p>Please ensure you are leaving at least 25 days between your holidays start date and today</p>

<form> 
<p>Please select the dates you wish to book a holiday for below</p>
<table> 
<tr>

<td style="width: 217px">Date from (DD/MM/YYYY)</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="lblDateStart" runat="server" width="150px" Text="01/06/2013" /><input   id="datepickerFrom" /></td>

<td style="width: 217px">Date to (DD/MM/YYYY)</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="lblDateEnd" runat="server" width="150px" Text="01/06/2014" /><input type="hidden" id="datepickerTo" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
<p></p>
<p>Please number of working days this includes</p>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddHolidayDays" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="99">Please Select</asp:ListItem>   
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>        
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="13">13</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="14">14</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="16">16</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="17">17</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="18">18</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="19">19</asp:ListItem>     
            <asp:ListItem Value="20">20</asp:ListItem>         

    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorWorkingDays" runat="server" Text="" visible="false" ForeColor="Red"/>

    <p></p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnRest" runat="server" Text="Reset"  CssClass="btnReset" /> 

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"   CssClass="btnSubmit" /> 

    <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
    Previous Holiday Requests

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." Width="770px" 
        Font-Size="Medium" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid"  
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">  

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Holiday Start Date" SortExpression="DateStart">
                <ItemTemplate>                
                   <asp:Label ID="DateStart" runat="server" Width="70px" Text='<%# DateTidy(Eval("DateStart")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>     
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Holiday End Date"  SortExpression="DateEnd">
                <ItemTemplate>                
                   <asp:Label ID="DateEnd" runat="server" Width="70px" Text='<%# DateTidy(Eval("DateEnd")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>     

            <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkingDays" HeaderText="Working Days Used" SortExpression="WorkingDays" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status"  SortExpression="Status" />

        </Columns>      

    </asp:GridView>
     </asp:Panel>
     <asp:Panel ID="PanelThankYou" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <div class="PageWrapper" > 
    <h2> Thank You</h2> <br />
    <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblThankYou" runat="server" Text="Label" />
         <br />

      <asp:Button ID="btnResetThanks" runat="server" Text="Click Here to request another holiday"  CssClass="btnReset" /> 
      </div> <!-- PageWrapper -->
    </asp:Panel>  

<!-- ######################### \\BODY CODE UNIQUE TO PAGE // ######################### -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server">
    <!-- ######################### //FOOTER CODE UNIQUE TO PAGE \\ ######################### -->


<p></p>

<!-- ######################### \\FOOTER CODE UNIQUE TO PAGE // ######################### -->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="SubTitle">
    <!-- '################################################################### -->
<!-- '################################################################### -->
<!-- '################################################################### --> 
<!-- '################################################################### -->

    <div id="MainTitleWrapper">

                    <div id="MainTitleBar1" class="MainTitleBar"> 
                    </div> <!-- MainTitleBar1 -->

                <div id="MainTitleContent">
                    <h1><img src="/gateway/images/gateway/Writing.png" alt="Writing Icon" />Request a Holiday Booking</h1>
                </div> <!-- MainTitleContent -->


                <div id="MainTitleBar2" class="MainTitleBar">
                </div> <!-- MainTitleBar2 -->


            <!-- '################################################################### -->
            <!-- '################################################################### -->
            <!-- '################################################################### --> 
            <!-- '################################################################### -->

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: deleted my answer since you said you checked for the spotted issue.

Comment: Amended text to reflect above (collapsar) - I have also asked the Server admin to check permissions for the folder